# PHP Can a base64 url string be too long to pass to variable via $_GET?

Tags: php, string, url, get, base64

Just as the title states, can a url string be too long to pass to a variable in php using the $_GET method?

I have 5 variables in my url string, 4 of them pass via $_GET perfectly but the 5th longer one wont? all 5 are base64 encoded and sanitized for use in the url string, but this 5th variable will not pass!

Ive changed the string to a short "TEST" and that sent fine, but change it back to the base64 and it wont work. Its appears in the address bar url string ok, but will not pass into php using $_GET

This is my url string

> script.php?xcas=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~&xsyn=QW4gYWN0b3IgKEZyZWVtYW4pIHByZXBwaW5nIGZvciBhbiB1cGNvbWluZyByb2xlIG1lZXRzIGEgcXVpcmt5IGdyb2NlcnkgY2xlcmsgKFZlZ2EpLCBhbmQgdGhlIHBhaXIgaGl0IHRoZSByb2FkIHRvIHNob3cgb25lIGFub3RoZXIgdGhlaXIgcmVzcGVjdGl2ZSB3b3JsZHMu&xdir=QnJhZCBTaWxiZXJsaW5n&xwri=QnJhZCBTaWxiZXJsaW5n&xrun=ODI~

Just change the tilde(~) to equals(=) to decode.

Any idea why?

Thanks.

edit* ps. its the xcas variable that wont pass.

Comment: There is a limit in theory, but not really in practical implementations. But why don't you simply check what comes out in `$_GET`?

Comment: I really think this is browser dependent. Max limit of the address bar.

Comment: I did, it doesnt even show as set when i check using isset.

Comment: yes, there is a length limit to GET requests - if you need to send large amounts of data then POST would be more efficient

Comment: Yes i was thinking POST might be my only option, but i was hoping to use this method.

Comment: Sounds more like you have to `suhosin` protection extension active...

Comment: any way to disable, or is it set by the hoster?